# How to get nearby location in a specific range?

Tags: geolocation, geohashing

I have a array of latitude and longitude and a center point.

```
{
  center: {
    lat: 10.002,
    lng: 20.003
  },
  all: [
    {
      lat: 20,
      lng: 50
    },
    {
      lat: 10,
      lng: 20.000001
    },
    // ...
  ]
}
```

I would like to know how do I get nearby locations in 10km or other specific range. Does there any keyword or library can help me do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can use geohash.
standard geohash can give you a good starting point, since the hash represents the location so you can group by the hash on certain mask based on your precision.
refer to: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash

this method is simple and there are lots of libraries out there.
but it also suffers from pole distortion and edge cases.

however I have implemented an alternative algorithm to solve those problems: https://github.com/linehrr/geohash
the drawback is that precision is pre-determined, so masking won't work since it's not linear.

hope this helps.